# Error with .bat and robocopy - hides the folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I am simply trying to copy `4` directories and an excel file, from the root of a drive to a destination.

My full hope is to make a backup from a Surface on Win 10 to an external drive. Then from that external drive to a server on a Win 7 computer. 
But first I need to make the backup from external drive to server on Win 7 computer to work.

```
E:\
|   Numbers.xlsx
|   
+---Four
|       FilesAndOrDirectories
|
+---One
|       FilesAndOrDirectories
|
+---Three
|       FilesAndOrDirectories
|
\---Two
        FilesAndOrDirectories
```

There appears to be no problem when I test with ordinary directories, e.g. `Robocopy E:\One C:\temp\test\`. The problem arises if I copy use the root of the drive: `Robocopy E:\ C:\temp\test`

The `test` folder seems to disappear, *but it is actually hidden*. The files are copied correctly. *(In the Command Prompt I can enter and view the files in that hidden directory)*.

I can make that directory visible again if I copy a directory to the same destination, e.g. `Robocopy E:\One C:\temp\test`. When I do this the test directory becomes visible!

I have tried both with and without `/mir`.

I have not found any similar questions elsewhere, is this a bug?

Comment: You should not ask two questions in one post...

Comment: Ok sorry. I edited my post to only contain one question and will create a new one for my other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds really similar to this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8dcb6432-6ae0-4816-92e8-2599e5e638f5/robocopy-hides-destination-directory?forum=w7itprogeneral

In the situation linked above, the user resolves an very similar issue by using a command that looks like this:

```
robocopy \\S09\S09_D\ "C:\Dropbox\S09_D" /mir /R:0 /W:0 /FFT /A-:SH
```

If that doesn't fix it, please share your whole command

Comment: Please add the relevant bits into your answer post! Regard that external linke could become invalid somewhen in future, so this answer became useless...

Comment: Thank you brazosFX. You guided me in to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

My problem for this question is solved.

The problem was copying from a directory root which inherits the system attributes. It also copied over the recycle bin as well as found.000

It helped by adding the following attributes to Robocopy 
/XD "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System volume information" "found.000" /XA:SH /A-:SH

/XA:SH is for excluding hidden and system files. 
/A-:SH is for not hiding the destination folder.